# Problem with Lagrange multiplier

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to find the minimum & maximum value of f. G is a square matrix. Applying Lagrange multiplier method,

How should I define the term '?', and how could I calculate the partial derivatives? 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to minimize (and maximize) 
$$ \Vert G u \Vert^2 \ \text{ subject to } \ \Vert u \Vert^2=1.  $$
The Lagrangien is given by
$$ \mathcal L(u,\lambda) =  \Vert G u \Vert^2 - \lambda( \Vert u \Vert^2 - 1), $$
and the first order condition is
$$ \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial u} (u, \lambda) = 2 G^\top Gu - 2 \lambda u  $$
meaning that $\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial u} (u, \lambda) = 0$ is possible for $u \neq 0$ only if $u$ is an eigenvector of $G^\top G$, in which case $\lambda$ is the corresponding eigenvalue.